How to pass variables to MUI styled label in ReactJs
Following is an example from MUI. Here I want to pass the myId variable in the label which creating the styled component so that I can uniquely identify it using the label. I could have gone down the by passing id to the component but that's not the route I want to go to because I dont want to add id to each and every element here.
So the expected label is MyThemeComponent-myId.
Any idea how can I achieve this?
import * as React from 'react';
import { styled, createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/system';

interface MyThemeComponentProps {
  color?: 'primary' | 'secondary';
  variant?: 'normal' | 'dashed';
}

const customTheme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MyThemeComponent: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          color: 'darkslategray',
        },
        primary: {
          color: 'darkblue',
        },
        secondary: {
          color: 'darkred',
          backgroundColor: 'pink',
        },
      },
      variants: [
        {
          props: { variant: 'dashed', color: 'primary' },
          style: {
            border: '1px dashed darkblue',
          },
        },
        {
          props: { variant: 'dashed', color: 'secondary' },
          style: {
            border: '1px dashed darkred',
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
});

const MyThemeComponent = styled('div', {
  // Configure which props should be forwarded on DOM
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) =>
    prop !== 'color' && prop !== 'variant' && prop !== 'sx',
  label: 'MyThemeComponent',
  slot: 'Root',
  // We are specifying here how the styleOverrides are being applied based on props
  overridesResolver: (props, styles) => [
    styles.root,
    props.color === 'primary' && styles.primary,
    props.color === 'secondary' && styles.secondary,
  ],
})<MyThemeComponentProps>(({ theme }) => ({
  backgroundColor: 'aliceblue',
  padding: theme.spacing(1),
}));

export default function UsingOptions() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>
      <MyThemeComponent sx={{ m: 1 }} color="primary" variant="dashed" myId={123}>
        Primary
      </MyThemeComponent>
      <MyThemeComponent sx={{ m: 1 }} color="secondary">
        Secondary
      </MyThemeComponent>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}


Here is the updated code:
import * as React from "react";
import { styled, createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/system";

// Create a wrapper for dynamic styling with a custom label
const dynamicStyled = (component, getLabel) => (styles) => {
  return styled(component, {
    shouldForwardProp: (prop) =>
      prop !== "color" &&
      prop !== "variant" &&
      prop !== "myId" &&
      prop !== "sx",
    label: (props) => getLabel(props),
    slot: "Root"
  })(styles);
};

const customTheme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MyThemeComponent: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          color: "darkslategray"
        },
        primary: {
          color: "darkblue"
        },
        secondary: {
          color: "darkred",
          backgroundColor: "pink"
        }
      },
      variants: [
        {
          props: { variant: "dashed", color: "primary" },
          style: {
            border: "1px dashed darkblue"
          }
        },
        {
          props: { variant: "dashed", color: "secondary" },
          style: {
            border: "1px dashed darkred"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});

const MyThemeComponent =
  dynamicStyled("div", (props) => `MyThemeComponent-${props.myId}`) 
  (({ theme }) => ({
    backgroundColor: "aliceblue",
    padding: theme.spacing(1)
  }));

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>
      <MyThemeComponent
        sx={{ m: 1 }}
        color="primary"
        variant="dashed"
        myId={123}
      >
        Primary
      </MyThemeComponent>
      <MyThemeComponent sx={{ m: 1 }} color="secondary" myId={456}>
        Secondary
      </MyThemeComponent>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}


The label is set by calling getLabel(props) which derives the label from the myId.
This approach ensures the label is dynamically generated without requiring explicit IDs or classes on individual elements.
Each instance of the component has a unique label (MyThemeComponent-123, MyThemeComponent-456, etc.).


You can only pass a string to label so label: (props) => getLabel(props) is invalid as it's not a string but a function that returns string
